# Shift dataset for neural network in R

Tags: r, neural-network, dataset

Ive been given an excel file (see below), which contains exchange rate values for each day for a number of days and have to use the following formula:

`Y(t+1) = f(Y(t), Y(t-1), Y(t-2))`

to shift the data below in order to create 3 more inputs for a neural network so that I have 4 columns of data to train and test the MLP neural network for time series predictions. 't' represents current value.

```
Exchange Values
1.0621
1.0791
1.0927
1.0906
1.0986
1.0918
1.0891
1.0817
1.0741
1.0767
1.0876
1.0876
1.1006
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Look at the `embed` function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `embed` function:

```
Exchange_Values <- scan(text="1.0621
1.0791
1.0927
1.0906
1.0986
1.0918
1.0891
1.0817
1.0741
1.0767
1.0876
1.0876
1.1006")
```

It lets you construct a matrix with "shifted" or offset in sequence values:

```
embed(Exchange_Values, 3)
        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
 [1,] 1.0927 1.0791 1.0621
 [2,] 1.0906 1.0927 1.0791
 [3,] 1.0986 1.0906 1.0927
 [4,] 1.0918 1.0986 1.0906
 [5,] 1.0891 1.0918 1.0986
 [6,] 1.0817 1.0891 1.0918
 [7,] 1.0741 1.0817 1.0891
 [8,] 1.0767 1.0741 1.0817
 [9,] 1.0876 1.0767 1.0741
[10,] 1.0876 1.0876 1.0767
[11,] 1.1006 1.0876 1.0876
```